# cloud firestore client offline access, online sync & billing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Will firestore redo all the (write/update) operations of a document, in the same order, when it syncs online or does it only update the online copy with just the latest cache copy ( which essentially impacts billing )

if the same document is updated multiple times when offline
will the online sync charge for all the operations or for the one final sync.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for asking a question nor does owning a business or company have anything to do with questions. You should take your comment here and to @dougstevenson answer and include it in the question because it clarifies it and makes the question more useful to future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore will only bill you for changes made while offline when the app comes back online and the changes are synchronized with the server.  If the app is never able to sync while online, then no there are no charges, as Firestore hasn't done any work in the cloud service.

Comment: Thanks, Doug, if the same document is updated multiple times when offline will the online sync charge for all the operations or for the one final sync.